# How do I get the JSON string from a URL?

Tags: javascript

All the answers that I've read so far were about making a xhr request, but that never works, because it gets blocked by the browser.

I've tried the following:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/usmap.jsp",
    type:"POST",
    data:"data",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(){
      alert("WORKS")
    }
  })
```

and

```
$.getJSON("https://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/usmap.jsp", function(data) { 
    alert(data)
   })
```

also,

```
   $.get("https://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/usmap.jsp", function(data) { 
        alert(data)
       })
```

They all return an error saying that the request is blocked, because ..*Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

In the book that I'm reading, the example they gave for getting a JSON string and using it for a Chrome extension is the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     $("#btn").click(function() { 
         $("#info").html("Getting information...");
         var code = $("#airportcode").val();
         $.get("http://services.faa.gov/airport/status" + code + "?format=application/json", "", function(data) { 
             displaydata(data);
         })
     })
 })
```

This isn't making a xhr request, right? I wanna take the JSON string from the same website, but it's not working, it keeps returning the above mentioned error.

I even tried it as an extension, and edited the `manifest` file to permit the website, but the result was the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The remote host does not allow CORS, it must explicitly allow access via javascript via cross origin headers. By default it will be blocked. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: You'll need to allow cross-origin requests in the API side.

Comment: You can try putting the site in an iframe and injecting JavaScript.

Comment: You will need to use a proxy either on your server or third party service

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ You can't access a cross origin frame from parent page either

Comment: @mousetail well, why isn't the last snippet getting blocked then?

Comment: @SonuBamniya I have no idea how to do that, and why is non of that required in my last snippet?

Comment: There is a difference between making a xhr request, and just getting a JSON string from a URL, right?

Comment: Apparently the other endpoint allows CORS

Comment: So, besides how do I allow the CORS, another thing I've confused about is, which JSON string am I getting? In the last snippet, the `status` page is suppose to return information about flights, so, will `https://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/usmap.jsp` this page return the same information? How do I know which page is going to return a JSON string? And also, is there a difference between making a xhr request, and trying to get the JSON string? Are they the same thing?

Comment: Can you also tell me how do I allow access to these websites? I briefly read the duplicates, but I didn't see where is this explained. They all seem to refer to a server made by the user, and they are suggesting editing the PHP. I am talking about getting JSON string from another website.